# IllegalArgumentException: Unknown URL content://com.android.calendar/events when inserting an event to the calendar on Android

Tags: android, calendar

I worked on an app that lets users create appointments and then inserts them into the Android calendar. I see a crash report from a user running Android version 4.0.4

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown URL content://com.android.calendar/events
at android.content.ContentResolver.insert(ContentResolver.java:726)
```

This works fine when I test it on my Android Phone, but I'm wondering what's wrong in this case?

edit: here's my code-

```
        ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(Events.DTSTART, startMillis);
        values.put(Events.DTEND, endMillis);
        values.put(Events.TITLE, title);
        values.put(Events.DESCRIPTION, location);
        values.put(Events.CALENDAR_ID, calID);
        values.put(Events.EVENT_TIMEZONE, TimeZone.getDefault().getDisplayName());
        Uri uri = cr.insert(Events.CONTENT_URI, values);
```

It's crashing on cr.insert(Events.CONTENT_URI, values) but only intermittently. So far only one crash report for this problem has been submitted.

Comment: Can you post your code, to know more exactly what's going on ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like that, instead of :

```
Uri uri = cr.insert(Events.CONTENT_URI, values);
```

use :

```
Uri uri = cr.insert(CalendarContract.Events.CONTENT_URI, values);
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this will fix this crash, but I'll accept the answer anyway. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You should accept the answer if you tested the solution, IMHO. By the way, there is no difference in these 2 sentences, they refer to the same field

Comment: This accepted answer does not work on Android 5.1 (API 22)